# Android 9-patch displays differently on different devices

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

I have a 9-patch which on my Nexus-4 and in Android Studio looks like this:

[image]

but when the same 9-patch is displayed on a Galaxy S3, it looks like this:

[image]

Which looks like it has been folded over. The same happens with a mirror image of that 9-patch.

Does anyone know what could make that happen?

EDIT -

This is the 9-patch (hdpi)

[image]

Comment: Post your 9 patch. So we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: It seems correct, even if bad quality (I see a lot of aliasing - it's like a sawtooth), and unoptimized. So, possibly there's some dpi issue or it's not put in the correct path (`/res/drawable`). Also make sure that the file extension is **.9.png** and you assign it as a `background`, not as a `src`.

Comment: It's not the best quality, but it's saved in the right place, as the right thing. I used Android Asset Studio to generate all the dpi versions.

Comment: Asset Studio, unfortunately, generates only **72 dpi** graphics... :(

Comment: But the Nexus 4 and S3 have almost identical dpi?

Comment: Yes, they both fall into the **xhdpi** category (approx. **320 dpi**): `LG Nexus 4: 768 x 1280 pixels, 4.7 inches (~318 ppi pixel density)`, `Samsung S3: 720 x 1280 pixels, 4.8 inches (~306 ppi pixel density)`

Comment: So if they both show the same 9patch, why would it display so differently when run on different devices with the same screen density?

Comment: Try this and see if it fixes up something: re-save your images at **320 dpi** and put them into `/res/drawable-xhdpi`. make sure the extension is **.9.png**. Use them as `background`, not as `src`.

Comment: tried saving at 320dpi, didn't work :(

Comment: did you put it in `/res/drawable-xhdpi`?